# Fraction of base-pair sequences

Tags: python, string, sequence

Given a string representing a base-pair sequence (i.e containing only the letters A, G, C and T), determine the fraction of G and C bases in the sequence. (Hint: strings have a count method, returning the number of occurrences of a substring)

Comment: What is the language (`C#`, `Java`, `Python`...)? And, please, provide your attempt: what have you tried so far?

Comment: The language is python. I haven't tried it at all. I'm actually a beginner

Comment: `fraction = (sequence.count('C') + sequence.count('G')) / len(sequence);`

Answer (score 0):

Given a `sequence`, e.g.

```
sequence = "ACGTAACCCTGATTTA";
```

we can well follow the **hint**:

> strings have a `count` method, returning the number of occurrences of a substring

So we can find number of `C` and `G` letters as

```
c = sequence.count('C');
g = sequence.count('G');
```

`sequence` length (number of all letters) can be computed with a help of `len()`:

```
total = len(sequence);
```

So

```
fraction = (c + g) / total
```

Or

```
fraction = (sequence.count('C') + sequence.count('G')) / len(sequence)
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I'mma go practice this